# Can't unsubscribe from SignalR events

Tags: asp.net, angular, signalr, broadcast, subscription

I have multiple `Angular` components that are subscribing to a `SignalR` hub connection. I have wrapped the `SignalR` hub connection object to an angular service, `hubconnection.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HubConnectionBuilder, HubConnection } from '@aspnet/signalr';

@Injectable()
export class HubConnectionService {
    public MyHubConnection: HubConnection;

    constructor() {
        this.MyHubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl('/sensorHub')
            .build();

        this.MyHubConnection
            .start()
            .then(() => console.log('[HubConnectionService] Connection started'))
            .catch(err => console.log('[HubConnectionService] Error while starting connection: ' + err));
    }
}
```

Now I have a component from where I want to subscribe to the data received through the `SignalR` hub, to do this I import my `SignalR` wrapper, and in the constructor I call the `.on()` method. To unsubscribe from that event I call the `.off()` method in the destructor:

```
export class RawdataComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private hubConnectionService: HubConnectionService) { }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.hubConnectionService.MyHubConnection.off('Broadcast');
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.hubConnectionService.MyHubConnection.on('Broadcast',
                function(sender, message) {
                  console.log('New message received: ' + message);
                });
    }
}
```

When I initially access the page that is described by this component, everything works as expected (`console.log()` is logging for every message I receive).

When I leave the page, `MyHubConnection.off('Broadcast');` is called. Then after I access the previous page again, the constructor is called and another subscription is made, but the previous one is not closed, and I get two `console.log()` calls.

Where's the mistake I'm making? Shouldn't `MyHubConnection.off('Broadcast');` close the current subscription when I leave the page?

Comment: did you found any solution to this problem? Thanks